# TypeError: Level type mismatch: 0.2. When splitting data into training, validating and testing sets

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, cross-validation

good day,

I am attempting to train, validate and test data without the usage of `scikit-learn`. 
I wish to split the data into the following samples:

- training data 0.7(70%)
- validating data 0.2(20%)
- testing data 0.1(10%)

However, when I attempt to split the data, I obtain the following error:

```
 TypeError: Level type mismatch: 6.0
```

I need help to understand what am I doing wrong here. The sample data and target data are `x_data` which is a data frame and `y_data` a Pandas series respectively. Here is the code I attempted below:

```
def train_valid_test(x_data y_data, train_split, valid_split, test_split):

    """ Parameters
    x_data: the input data
    y_data: target values 
    train_split: the portion used for training data 
    valid_split: the portion used for validating data
    test_split: the portion used for testing data 
    """ 

    # setting sizes to split the data into training validating and testing samples accordingly 
    train_size = float(len(all_x)*0.7)
    valid_size = float(len(all_x)*0.2)
    test_size = float(len(x_prime)*0.1)

    # Creating Training and Validation sets
    x_train, x_prime = x_data[:valid_size], x_data[valid_size:]
    y_train, y_prime = y_data[:valid_size], y_data[valid_size:]

    # Creating test sets
    x_valid, x_test = x_prime[:test_size], x_prime[test_size:]
    y_valid, y_test = y_prime[:test_size], y_prime[test_size:]


    # Return the samples 
    return X_train, X_valid, X_test, y_train, y_valid, y_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to slice a pandas dataframe with a `float` as the following operations generate non-integer values for the size of training, validation and test data:

```
train_size = float(len(all_x)*0.7)
valid_size = float(len(all_x)*0.2)
test_size = float(len(x_prime)*0.1)
```

Note that your split is incorrect; Your training set includes all the data points of validation and test sets while your validation set contains all the instances of test set. Also, you should never rely on splits that do not shuffle your dataset. The following function should do the trick for you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def train_valid_test(df, train_split=.7, valid_split=.2, seed=None):    
    np.random.seed(seed)
    perm = np.random.permutation(df.index)

    training_max_index = int(train_split * len(df.index))
    validate_max_index = int(valid_split * len(df.index)) + training_max_index

    training = df.ix[perm[:training_max_index]]
    validation = df.ix[perm[training_max_index:validate_max_index]]
    test = df.ix[perm[validate_max_index:]]

    return training, validation, test
```

In case you want to pass dependent (`y`) and independent(`x`) variables separately, you can use the following function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def train_valid_test(x_data, y_data, train_split=.7, valid_split=.2, seed=None):
    if len(x_data.index) != len(y_data.index):
        raise Exception('x_data and y_data must contain the same number of data points'

    np.random.seed(seed)
    perm = np.random.permutation(x_data.index)
    x_data = x_data.reindex(perm)
    y_data = y_data.reindex(perm)

    training_max_index = int(train_split * len(x_data.index))
    validate_max_index = int(valid_split * len(x_data.index)) + training_max_index

    X_train, y_train = x_data[:training_max_index], y_data[:training_max_index]
    X_valid, y_valid = x_data[:validate_max_index], y_data[:validate_max_index]
    X_test, y_test = x_data[validate_max_index:], y_data[validate_max_index:]

    return X_train, X_valid, X_test, y_train, y_valid, y_test
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one question for clarification. I used a variable `test size` and you did not. Was it not needed? or was `validate_max_index `considered the test size in your example?

Comment: @DeepakM The test set includes all the remaining data points which are not included in training and validation sets. You don’t need to calculate the size explicitly as soon as you know the maximum index of validation set. In order to construct the test set you just need to take the data points from ‘validate_max_index’ onwards.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I Marked your answer as the solution to this problem. Just one last question. For future reference If I had to explicitly show/ calculate the `test_size`. How would it be done?

Comment: test_size = int((1 - train_split - valid_split) * len(x_data.index)) + validate_max_index

Answer (score 0):

Indices need to be integer. May be try:

```py
    train_size = int(len(all_x)*0.7)
    valid_size = int(len(all_x)*0.2)
    test_size = int(len(x_prime)*0.1)
```